# Dynamically select property in Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am facing one issue with linq query in c# , my linq query as per below

```
list = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select new Perfmon
                            {
                                id = row.Field<long>("id"),
                                counter1 = row.Field<string>("counter"),

                            }).ToList();
```

I have one **perfmon** class and it contains properties like (id, counter1, counter2 ...)
there are more then 20 counters now i  have developed sql query to select id and counter based on passed countername in parameter e.g. if i have passed counter1 then it will select id , counter1 (renamed as counter) only

if i will use switch case here then it will have 20 witch case, can anyone please help me how can bind property dynamically in linq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your Perfmon class backed by a dictionary rather than fields per properties. like:

```
class Perfmon
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _counters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Perfmon(params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] knownCounters)
    {
        foreach (var knownCounter in knownCounters)
        {
            SetCounter(knownCounter.Key, knownCounter.Value);
        }
    }   
    public void SetCounter(string name, string value)
    {
        _counters[name] = value;
    }

    protected string GetCounterValue(string name)
    {
        if (_counters.ContainsKey(name))
            return _counters[name];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Counter1 { get { return GetCounterValue("Counter1"); } }
    public string Counter2 { get { return GetCounterValue("Counter2"); } }
    public string Counter3 { get { return GetCounterValue("Counter3"); } }
}
```

The constructor is there so you can easily use it in your query like:

```
var counterName = "Counter2";
list = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                            select new Perfmon(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(counterName, row.Field<string>("counter")))
                            { 
                                id = row.Field<long>("id")
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Liked the implementation. After all, the properties are key value pair. +1 for it.

Comment: u can solve the bug for the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096029/i-need-to-select-particular-column-based-on-check-box-list-in-linq-c-net#comment14559726_11096029

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Dynamic Linq**. The essence is to parse your string and convert it in to expression trees. See here for more details

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the `System.Reflection` namespace. Sure, you want to use it within a linq query, but the thing you can't seem to do, for now, is to dynamically extract a field/property from a class.

Try to use it outside a linq query, and then you'll find a way to integrate it into your query.

Comment: This is a valid solution, imho, but if you don't mind changing the Perfmon class, I suggest you to go with @Polity's answer. I think it's cleaner, and will most likely be more performant.