# Implementing Dynamic LINQ querying in MVC5/EF Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, epplus

As an overview I am attempting to add `Export()` functionality to my application -- allowing the user to specify certain model fields and only export the values in those fields by querying with LINQ and using the [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) library to Export. I am attempting to implement Dynamic LINQ functionality in my MVC5/EF Code-First application based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096029/i-need-to-select-particular-column-based-on-check-box-list) example, but seem to be missing some things to get it working or not understanding something.

First I added a new class file to my main project folder called `DynamicLibrary.cs`. When I download the .zip [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx), I "believe" the code I wanted was the `Dynamic.cs` file code which I copied into `DynamicLibrary.cs` in my project. Doing this allowed me to reference `using System.Linq.Dynamic` in my project.

Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to setup the rest for Dynamic LINQ.

In my `ExportController` within the `namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers {}` but outside the `public class ExportController : Controller { }` I added the example code based upon the fields in my `INV_Assets` model I am attempting to Export:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;


namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
{
    public class ExportController : Controller
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();

        // GET: Export
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ExportAssetsViewModel expViewMod = new ExportAssetsViewModel();
            return View(expViewMod);
        }

        public ActionResult Export()
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = _db.INV_Assets.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
        {
            //FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo(output);
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");  

            var exportFields = new List<string>();
            foreach(var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
            {
                // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
                exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
            }

            // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
            for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++ )
            {
                ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
            }

            // INVALID - Need to query table INV_Assets for all values of selected fields and insert into appropriate columns.
            if (exportFields.Count() > 0)
            {
                var exportAssets = from ia in _db.INV_Assets
                                   select new {
                                       ia.ip_address,

                                   }
                ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(exportFields);
            }

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

            string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
        }

    }

    public class DynamicColumns : INV_Assets
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        //public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }
        //public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }
        //public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }
        //public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }
        //public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }
        //public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public string mac_address { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int invoice_number { get; set; }
        public string serial_number { get; set; }
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }
        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EnumTasks
    {
        Model = 1,
        Manufacturer = 2,
        Type = 3,
        Location = 4,
        Vendor = 5,
        Status = 6,
        ip_address = 7,
        mac_address = 8,
        note = 9,
        owner = 10,
        cost = 11,
        po_number = 12,
        description = 13,
        invoice_number = 14,
        serial_number = 15,
        asset_tag_number = 16,
        acquired_date = 17,
        disposed_date = 18,
        verified_date = 19,
        created_date = 20,
        created_by = 21,
        modified_date = 22,
        modified_by = 23
    }

     public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns()
    {
        using (var db = new TrackerDataContext())
        {
            string fieldIds = "," + "4,5,3,2,6,17,11,12" + ",";

            var taskColum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTasks)).Cast<EnumTasks>().Where(e => fieldIds.Contains("," + ((int)e).ToString() + ",")).Select(e => e.ToString().Replace("_", ""));

            string select = "new (  TaskId, " + (taskColum.Count() > 0 ? string.Join(", ", taskColum) + ", " : "") + "Id )";

            return db.Task.ToList().Select(t => new DynamicColumns() { Id = t.Id, TaskId = Project != null ? Project.Alias + "-" + t.Id : t.Id.ToString(), ActualTime = t.ActualTime, AssignedBy = t.AssignedBy.ToString(), AssignedDate = t.AssignedDate, AssignedTo = t.AssignedTo.ToString(), CreatedDate = t.CreatedDate, Details = t.Details, EstimatedTime = t.EstimatedTime, FileName = t.FileName, LogWork = t.LogWork, Module = t.Module != null ? t.Module.Name : "", Priority = t.Priority != null ? t.Priority.Name : "", Project = t.Project != null ? t.Project.Name : "", ResolveDate = t.ResolveDate, Status = t.Status != null ? t.Status.Name : "", Subject = t.Subject, TaskType = t.TaskType != null ? t.TaskType.Type : "", Version = t.Version != null ? t.Version.Name : "" }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure this is set up in the right location. The last method below has 5 errors:

- `IQueryable` - `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.`
- `InventoryTrackerContext` - `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.`
- `DynamicColumns()` - `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.`
- Closing `}` for `public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns()` - `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.`
- Closing `}` for `namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers` - `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.`

  ```
  public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns()
  {
      using (var db = new InventoryTrackerContext())
      {
          string fieldIds = "," + "4,5,3,2,6,17,11,12" + ",";

          var taskColum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTasks)).Cast<EnumTasks>().Where(e => fieldIds.Contains("," + ((int)e).ToString() + ",")).Select(e => e.ToString().Replace("_", ""));

          string select = "new (  TaskId, " + (taskColum.Count() > 0 ? string.Join(", ", taskColum) + ", " : "") + "Id )";

          return db.Task.ToList().Select(t => new DynamicColumns() { Id = t.Id, TaskId = Project != null ? Project.Alias + "-" + t.Id : t.Id.ToString(), ActualTime = t.ActualTime, AssignedBy = t.AssignedBy.ToString(), AssignedDate = t.AssignedDate, AssignedTo = t.AssignedTo.ToString(), CreatedDate = t.CreatedDate, Details = t.Details, EstimatedTime = t.EstimatedTime, FileName = t.FileName, LogWork = t.LogWork, Module = t.Module != null ? t.Module.Name : "", Priority = t.Priority != null ? t.Priority.Name : "", Project = t.Project != null ? t.Project.Name : "", ResolveDate = t.ResolveDate, Status = t.Status != null ? t.Status.Name : "", Subject = t.Subject, TaskType = t.TaskType != null ? t.TaskType.Type : "", Version = t.Version != null ? t.Version.Name : "" }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);
      }
  }
  ```

Can anyone with more experience in this kind of thing weigh-in? I also checked out [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), but seem to be missing or not understanding something.

---

**EDIT**:

**REDACTED FOR SPACE**

---

**EDIT2**:

Using the return from `DynamicSelectionColumns()` into my variable `selectStatement`, I have the following coded:

```
    public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns(List<string> fieldsForExport)
    {
        using (var db = new InventoryTrackerContext())
        {
            string fieldIds = "," + "4,5,3,2,6,17,11,12" + ",";

            var taskColum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTasks)).Cast<EnumTasks>().Where(e => fieldIds.Contains("," + ((int)e).ToString() + ",")).Select(e => e.ToString().Replace("_", ""));

            //string select = "new (  TaskId, " + (taskColum.Count() > 0 ? string.Join(", ", taskColum) + ", " : "") + "Id )";
            string select = "new (  " + string.Join(", ", fieldsForExport) + ")";

            //return db.INV_Assets.ToList().Select(t => new DynamicColumns() { Id = t.Id, TaskId = Project != null ? Project.Alias + "-" + t.Id : t.Id.ToString(), 
             return db.INV_Assets.ToList().Select(t => new DynamicColumns() { 
                Id = t.Id, 
                Manufacturer = Convert.ToString(t.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description), 
                Type = t.Type.type_description, 
                Location = t.Location.location_room, 
                Vendor = t.Vendor.vendor_name, 
                Status = t.Status.status_description, 
                ip_address = t.ip_address, 
                mac_address = t.mac_address, 
                note = t.note, 
                owner = t.owner, 
                //Module = t.Module != null ? t.Module.Name : "", 
                cost = t.cost,
                po_number = t.po_number,
                description = t.description,
                invoice_number = t.invoice_number,
                serial_number = t.serial_number,
                asset_tag_number = t.asset_tag_number,
                acquired_date = t.acquired_date,
                disposed_date = t.disposed_date,
                verified_date = t.verified_date,
                created_date = t.created_date,
                created_by = t.created_by,
                modified_date = t.modified_date,
                modified_by = t.modified_by
            }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");  

        var exportFields = new List<string>();
        foreach(var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
        {
            // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
            exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
        }

        var selectStatement = DynamicSelectionColumns(exportFields);

        // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
        for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++ )
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
        }

        if (selectStatement.Count() > 0)
        {
            ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement.ToString());
        }

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

This yields an Excel output with columns [ip_address], [mac_address], [note], [owner], and [cost] (the fields I selected), but no data. Instead of data, I get 251 rows of `0` in column A and nothing in the others.

How do I implement the dynamic select query results into my Excel spreadsheet?

---

**EDIT3**:

Attempting [ThulasiRam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085778/thulasiram)'s suggestion (ExportController below):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;


namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
{
    public class ExportController : Controller
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();
        public static List<DynamicColumns> DynamicColumnsCollection = new List<DynamicColumns>();

        [HttpPost]
```

public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        //FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo(output);
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

```
    var exportFields = new List<string>();
    foreach(var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
    {
        // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
        exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    foreach(var column in exportFields)
    {
        DynamicColumnsCollection.Add(new DynamicColumns()
        {
            Id = cnt,

            ip_address = "ip_address" + cnt,
            mac_address = "mac_address" + cnt,
            note = "note" + cnt,
            owner = "owner" + cnt,
            cost = "cost" + cnt,
            po_number = "po_number" + cnt,
            description = "description" + cnt,
            invoice_number = "invoice_number" + cnt,
            serial_number = "serial_number" + cnt,
            asset_tag_number = "asset_tag_number" + cnt,
            acquired_date = "acquired_date" + cnt,
            disposed_date = "disposed_date" + cnt,
            verified_date = "verified_date" + cnt,
            created_date = "created_date" + cnt,
            created_by = "created_by" + cnt,
            modified_date = "modified_date" + cnt,
            modified_by = "modified_by" + cnt
        });
    }

    //var selectStatement = DynamicSelectionColumns(exportFields);
    IQueryable collection = DynamicSelectionColumns(new List<string>() {
        "id",
        "owner",
        "note"
    });

    // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
    for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++ )
    {
        ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
    }

    ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(collection.ToString());

    //    ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement.ToString());

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

    string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
    string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
}

        public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns(List<string> fieldsForExport)
        {
            using (var db = new InventoryTrackerContext())
            {

                if (!fieldsForExport.Any())
                {
                    return null;
                }

                string select = string.Format("new ( {0} )", string.Join(", ", fieldsForExport.ToArray()));

                var collection = DynamicColumnsCollection.Select(t => new DynamicColumns()
                    {
                        Id = t.Id,
                        //Manufacturer = Convert.ToString(t.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description),
                        //Type = t.Type.type_description,
                        //Location = t.Location.location_room,
                        //Vendor = t.Vendor.vendor_name,
                        //Status = t.Status.status_description,
                        ip_address = t.ip_address,
                        mac_address = t.mac_address,
                        note = t.note,
                        owner = t.owner,
                        //Module = t.Module != null ? t.Module.Name : "", 
                        cost = t.cost,
                        po_number = t.po_number,
                        description = t.description,
                        invoice_number = t.invoice_number,
                        serial_number = t.serial_number,
                        asset_tag_number = t.asset_tag_number,
                        acquired_date = t.acquired_date,
                        disposed_date = t.disposed_date,
                        verified_date = t.verified_date,
                        created_date = t.created_date,
                        created_by = t.created_by,
                        modified_date = t.modified_date,
                        modified_by = t.modified_by
                    }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);

                return collection;


        }

    }

    public class DynamicColumns : INV_Assets
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public string mac_address { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public string cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string invoice_number { get; set; }
        public string serial_number { get; set; }
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }
        public string acquired_date { get; set; }
        public string disposed_date { get; set; }
        public string verified_date { get; set; }
        public string created_date { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        public string modified_date { get; set; }
        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EnumTasks
    {
        Model = 1,
        Manufacturer = 2,
        Type = 3,
        Location = 4,
        Vendor = 5,
        Status = 6,
        ip_address = 7,
        mac_address = 8,
        note = 9,
        owner = 10,
        cost = 11,
        po_number = 12,
        description = 13,
        invoice_number = 14,
        serial_number = 15,
        asset_tag_number = 16,
        acquired_date = 17,
        disposed_date = 18,
        verified_date = 19,
        created_date = 20,
        created_by = 21,
        modified_date = 22,
        modified_by = 23
    }
```

What I can't figure out is where to put this relevant piece of code from their suggestion (or set it up) within my MVC application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IQueryable collection = DynamicSelectionColumns(new List<string>() { "id", "name" });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Any thoughts? I'm not sure how to structure the `static Program()` or `Main()` used in the example for my MVC app. In my code listed above (should I select just the `note`/`owner` field), I receive an output Excel sheet with `"note"` in `A1`, `"owner"` in `B1`, and then just the number `0` in cells `A2:A180`...?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem now. Can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: The part about selecting the `fieldIds`, the `GetValues()` for `taskColum`, and the `select`. The `select` (if I'm reading correclty) builds the `select` query by counting the values for the `taskColum` variable and using their `fieldId`? The example code was seeking a `TaskId` and I'm not sure what all needs modified to work for my own use -- I believe I've correclty setup code for the `return`, but the first part still has me a bit lost. I'm unsure how to use the `DynamicSelectionColumns()` function to dynamically search for my fields.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you're getting has nothing to do with linq or the other libraries you imported into your project.

You're declaring the function `DynamicSelectionColumns` in the namespace, not in the `ExportController` class.

**After your Edit:**

if your `exportFields` is already a list of `Task` columns, you can simply pass that list to `DynamicSelectionColumns` and have this inside:

```
string select = "new (  " + string.Join(", ", exportFields) + ")";
```

**After Edit2:**

Replace

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement.ToString());
```

with

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement, false);
```

**After Edit3:**

After this trial and error approaches, I decided to indeed lookup the EPPlus library you mentioned. I found out that **you don't need** any of this DynamicQuery. You can specify into `LoadFromCollection` the fields you want to show.
I didn't get to compile this (because it's your code) but It worked on my machine with fake data.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.IO;
    using InventoryTracker.DAL;
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using InventoryTracker.Models;
    using System.Reflection;
    using OfficeOpenXml.Table;


    namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
    {
        public class ExportController : Controller
        {
            private InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
            {
                //FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo(output);
                ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
                var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

                var exportFields = new List<string>();
                foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
                {
                    // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
                    exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
                }

                // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
                for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
                }

                var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Asset).GetMembers()
                    .Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name))
                    .ToArray();

                ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);


                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

                string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
                string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've moved the class as you suggested which got rid of my previous listed errors, but I'm still trying to figure out how to set up the Dynamic LINQ code for my own use. Please see EDIT above.

Comment: Regarding "After your Edit": Once I call `DynamicSelectionColumns(List<string> exportFields)`, what do I do on the return? How do I do the actual querying towards `INV_Assets` based on user selected fields?

Comment: please see my EDIT2 above.

Comment: Regarding "After Edit2": `ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement, false);` yields `"The type arguments for method 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromCollection<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."`....?

Comment: It's a long shot, but can you try `ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement.Cast<object>(), false);` for the generic version of IQueriable.

Comment: Ok, when I try that I still (when selecting just `note`/`owner` for the fields) get nothing in column B for `owner`, but column A for `note` has all the values (Ex. "`{note=Power Cable is frayed., owner=John Smith}`" for each record appropriately. Is there a way to get these individually in the right columns instead of one giant string in column A? EDIT: I have confirmed all selected fields come through, but as a long string in column A.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. TaskId property not exist in DynamicColumns class.

2. Remove .Replace("_", "") from
   var taskColum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTasks)).Cast<EnumTasks>().Where(e => fieldIds.Contains("," + ((int)e).ToString() + ",")).Select(e => e.ToString().Replace("_", ""));

3.exportFields.Count should be > 0.


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace Dynamic
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static List<DynamicColumns> DynamicColumnsCollection = new List<DynamicColumns>();

        static Program()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DynamicColumnsCollection.Add(new DynamicColumns() { Id = i, Name = "Name" + i, ip_address = "ip_" + i });
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQueryable collection = DynamicSelectionColumns(new List<string>() { "id", "name" });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class DynamicColumns
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string ip_address { get; set; }
        }

        public static IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns(List<string> fieldsForExport)
        {
            if (!fieldsForExport.Any())
                return null;

            string select = string.Format("new ( {0} )", string.Join(", ", fieldsForExport.ToArray()));

            var collection = DynamicColumnsCollection.Select(t => new DynamicColumns()
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Name = t.Name,
                ip_address = t.ip_address,
            }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);

            return collection;
        }
    }
}
```

Further any problem let me know.

Regards,

Ram.S

Comment: thanks for responding. I seem to be having some trouble with figuring out how to setup the code you have used in `Program()/Main()` within my MVC application. Please see my EDIT3 above.